# Installing the SSRS Data Connector for CRM4

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to install the SSRS data connector for my CRM4 implementation.
I'm using the [Method 2: Modify the Install-config.xml file from this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947060). But keep getting the same error message:

> Unable to validate SQL Server Reporting Services Report Server
>   installation. Please check that it is correctly installed on the local
>   machine.

I've added the following to my XML file.

```
<reportserverurl>http://SSRS-Server/Reportserver$MYORG_MSCRM</reportserverurl>
<instancename>MYORG_MSCRM</instancename>
```

Anyone know what is still wrong?
I tried several instance names but they all don't work either.
I can access my SSRS server by going to `http://SSRS-Server/Reports` and it will give a list of all services running there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to post more details regarding this issue:
1) The 2nd method described in this link : [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947060) is used when the Reporting Server database is installed using the SQL Server named instance. Are you installing the Reporting Server database in the default instance or named instance ?

2) If you are using default instance, you might not need to use custom XML, you can just run the installer without requiring the input XML file.

3) What is the architecture of your CRM implementation ? is the CRM Application, SQL server and Reporting Server resided in the same server ? or different server ?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a really old article however I wanted to post the resolution I found to work as I have spent the past 3 days trying to resolve this issue! I created an account just to post this.

I was having the same problem as the original article. I had SSRS 2008 installed on a server, CRM (4.0!!!) on a different server and SQL 2008 on a different server again. When all permission issues were resolved and ports were opened from the SSRS server to the SQL server, I was still having problems getting the SetupSrsDataConnector.exe to see the locally installed instance of SSRS2008 (Not R2).

I found the resolution to the issue in this article: 
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/pabloperalta/archive/2011/07/12/unable-to-validate-sql-server-reporting-services-report-server-installation-error-while-installing-srs-data-connector

Effectively the problem I was having is that my copy of the SRS Connector installation files were old and needed updating, however my server did not have internet connectivity. In the link above, it gives you a download location to get a .mps file which contains the updates for the SRS Connector.

You need to download this .mps file and then run the installation via command prompt with a customised install-config.xml file, which specifies the SSRS ReportServer URL and the SSRS Instance Name in a custom tag (what you named the SSRS instance when you installed it) and another custom tag for <*Patch update="true">C:\Path to the .msp file< /Patch*>

This was my installation command:
"D:\Stage\SRSDataConnector\SetupSrsDataConnector.exe" /CONFIG "D:\Stage\SRSDataConnectorUpdates\install-config.xml"